# does bp need to be simultanious? - XOR learning problem

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I have a problem with XOR learning.
I have 2(inputs),2,1(output) neuron neural network with sigmoidal function and normal sets

```
(0,0.9)->0.9
(0.9,0.9)->0.1
(0.9,0.1)->0.9
(0.1,0.1)->0.1
```

of learning sets, plus bias neuron with 1.0 output connected to hidden layer and output layer. Despite changing biased neuron output and randomizing order of using learning set, the usual output of this network is like:

```
0.5070491199305279
0.506573763380741
0.5065628483577969
0.5070403151187465
```

which is zero given to sigmoidal function and mostly they tend to return almost the same output.

```
like
0.4308536422848425
0.4308546005321358
0.43085460201816195
0.4308536440377257
```

Do you think that this is problem concerned with a fact that my backpropagation isn't simultaneous (I change weights every one case not after full set). Or maybe my network is missing something?

Values of inputs and outputs for third case;

[image: third case]

Answer (score 0):

I've got analog problem myself, when I was looking for the minimal neuron network architecture required to learn XOR which should be a (2,2,1) network. In fact, maths shows that the (2,2,1) network can solve the XOR problem, but maths doesn't show that the (2,2,1) network is easy to learn. That said, I've got easily good results with (2,3,1) or (2,4,1) network architectures.

The problem seems to be related to the existence of many local minima. Look at this 1998 paper, «[Learning XOR: exploring the space of a classic problem](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/%7Ekjt/techreps/pdf/TR148.pdf)» by Richard Bland. Maybe you could try different random initialization of the weights or change your loss function.

It works fine with Keras or TensorFlow using loss function 'mean_squared_error', sigmoid activation and Adam optimizer. Furthermore weights initialization with random number between 0.5 and 1.0 helps to converge. Even with pretty good hyperparameters, I observed that the learned XOR model is trapped in a local minimum about 15% of the time.